# VBA Splitting array difficulties

Tags: arrays, vba, modulus

So I am trying to split an array into two halves and am having allot more trouble than I anticipated. 
Setting break points, I know that as these lines are being executed "sz"(Integer) is set to 9. This code sets "rightSz"(Integer) to be 4, which is what I expected, but it also sets "leftSz"(Integer) to be equal to 6. I have no idea why it is giving me this and it is causing a lot of problems in later sections of my code.

```
If sz Mod 2 = 1 Then
               rightSz = sz / 2
               leftSz = rightSz + 1
        Else
                leftSz = sz / 2
                rightSz = sz / 2
        End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach, using the `Int()` function to round down half of the original number to a whole number. The other half is calculated by computing the difference from the original. Might be slightly less confusing if people are not as familiar with `Mod`.

```
Public Sub TestSplitArray()

    Dim sz As Integer
    Dim intPart1 As Integer
    Dim intPart2 As Integer

    sz = 9

    intPart1 = Int(sz / 2)
    intPart2 = sz - intPart1

    Debug.Print "sz=(" & intPart1 & "+" & intPart2 & ")"

End Sub
```

Also note that `/` is not the same as `\` when it comes to division in VBA. The forward slash returns the fraction, while the backslash returns a whole number. Using this concept, you could use the backslash instead of the `Int()` function to yield the same result.

```
Public Sub TestSplitArray()

    Dim sz As Integer
    Dim intPart1 As Integer
    Dim intPart2 As Integer

    sz = 9

    intPart1 = sz \ 2
    intPart2 = sz - intPart1

    Debug.Print "sz=(" & intPart1 & "+" & intPart2 & ")"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code seems right, it could be an issue with the dimensioning of the variables

This one makes `leftSz == 5` and `rightsz == 4`

```
Sub test()
    Dim sz As Long, leftsz As Long, rightsz As Long
    sz = 9

    If sz Mod 2 = 1 Then
           rightsz = sz / 2
           leftsz = rightsz + 1
    Else
            leftsz = sz / 2
            rightsz = sz / 2
    End If
End Sub
```